# Check to see if background image source exists, with an increasing counter?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have an image gallery on my site, where I have a counter in the background image source, and when a button is clicked, the counter goes up, changing the background image.

But I want the counter to reset, if the image file doesn't exist.

How would I achieve this?

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<button>click</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

var counter = 1;

div.style.backgroundImage = "url(image1.jpg)";

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  counter++;
  div.style.backgroundImage = "url(image" + counter + ".jpg)";
  console.log(counter + " " + div.style.backgroundImage);

  if (div.style.backgroundImage === undefined) { counter = 1 } // something like this?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no JS callbacks for css styles. There is no way to know if a background image loaded successfully or not wait plain JS. It is necessary to load the image twice - once to check.

For that, you can use something like this:

```
function imageExists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;

}
```

And refactor your code to pass the image url to the function.

```
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var button = document.querySelector("button");

var counter = 1;

div.style.backgroundImage = "url(image1.jpg)";

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  counter++;
  var imageUrl = "image" + counter;
  if (imageExists(imageUrl)){
     //Image can be loaded
     div.style.backgroundImage = "url(image" + counter + ".jpg)";
     console.log(counter + " " + div.style.backgroundImage);
  } else {
     //Image cannot be loaded
     counter = 1;
     div.style.backgroundImage = "url(image" + counter + ".jpg)";
  }
   // something like this?
});
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this. This works and I managed to implement it into my project... however, when the image isn't uploaded, the counter gets reset back to 1, BUT the source is still increasing by 1. So what I'm seeing is when the image isn't loaded `counter = 1` but `url(image2.jpg)`.